# Use Recursion to Create a Countdown | FreeCodeCamp Recursion problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion, printing

```js
var a=[];
// Only change code below this line
function countdown(n){
  
  if(n>=1){
    
    countdown(n-1);
    console.log(n);
    a.push(n);
    return a;
  }
  else{
    return [];
  }
}
console.log(countdown(5));
```

Here I want to know after the recalling of the countdown function why the n is printed like 1,2,3,4,5? It should be 5,4,3,2,1?

Comment: Because the first statement after `if` is `countdown(n-1);`, before any `console.log` executes

Comment: What is the point of `a`?

Answer (score 0):

In the initial call to `countdown` (where `n`=5) you recursively call `countdown` and *then* print `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of `console.log(n);` and `countdown(n-1);` and you will have expected behavior.

```js
var a=[];
// Only change code below this line
function countdown(n){
  
  if(n>=1){
    
    console.log(n);
    countdown(n-1);
    a.unshift(n);
    return a;
  }
  else{
    return [];
  }
}
console.log(countdown(5));
```